# Warning: strtoupper() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I have the following code in my functions.php on my wordpress website. it allows me to control companycodes in a gravityform. But I want the validation to work on all forms but when I change `gform_field_validation_5_6` to `gform_field_validation` (from working on one form to all forms) I get this error:

> Warning: strtoupper() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/...

The code i use:

```
/**
 * Validate the submitted Company Code
 *
 * @since      2016-07-30
 * @author     Dave Clements
 * @link       https://www.randomlists.com/string Random String Generator to create new company codes
 * @link       https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/gform_field_validation/ Documentation on gform_field_validation()
 * @param      array        $result The validation result to be filtered.
 * @param      string|array $value The field value to be validated.
 * @param      array        $form The Form Object.
 * @param      array        $field The Field Object.
 * @return     array        The filtered $result
 */
function validate_company_code( $result, $value, $form, $field ) {
    $valid_company_codes = array(
        '6XZTPWF3' => 'Company name',
        '6XZTPWF3' => 'Company name',
        '7DJEHMM7' => 'Company name',
        '6XZTPWF3' => 'Company name',
    );
    // Allow user entry to include lower-case letters.
    $capitalized_value = strtoupper( $value );
    // Check if the entered code is valid.
    if ( ! array_key_exists( $capitalized_value, $valid_company_codes ) ) {
        $result['is_valid'] = false;
        $result['message'] = 'That company code appears to be invalid. Please try again.';
    }
    return $result;
}
add_filter( 'gform_field_validation', 'validate_company_code', 10, 4 );
```

Any ideas what is causing this error.

Comment: Your `$value` is an array.

Comment: strtoupper() can only handle strings. $value is an array.

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming you have a simple array.

```
if(is_array($value)){
  $capitalized_value = strtoupper($value[0]);
} else {
  $capitalized_value = strtoupper($value);
}
```

If you want to pass in multiple values. the function will need major changes.